# How do I disable the cache?

Tags: caching

I have created the settings.local.php file inside the default folder and uncommented the the following lines.

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

I also uncommented code in settings.php file, but Drupal is still caching the code. What's the solution for this? I am using Drupal 8.6.10.

I added these parameters in the development.services.yml file.

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto-reload: true
    cashe: false
```

The settings.php file contains the following lines.

```
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
   include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

Comment: `cache` is spelled with two `c`'s; it's not `cashe` as you have in your dev services file

Answer (score 1):

The Page Cache and Dynamic Page Cache store complete pages, but Drupal also uses the Render Cache to store page fragments (e.g. the teaser display of each node).

To disable the render cache, set it to use the null backend as well:

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```